# Internal Server Error - Refused to execute a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm running a basic Node app on Heroku (using Express and EJS).
Whenever I first load the page I always get a blank screen with 'Internal Server Error', whenever I reload the page my content shows up just fine and my scripts execute.

When checking the console logs I get:
*Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy. Refused to load myHerokuURL because it appears in neither the img-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.*

I'v researched this and this would point on my script being in my HTML inline, however there is not a single inline script use on my HTML (EJS) file.

I'm not sure what is causing my internal server error, I'm scraping data from another website to display on mine, perhaps this could point on my script.js executing before my node app has pulled all the info it needs? If so, how could I prevent this from happening?

If anyone could point me in the right direction of solving this issue, it would be greatly appreciated, code posted below.

My EJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- icons stylesheet  -->
    <title>Music Scraper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class=header>
        <div class=header-title>
        
            <h1>MUSICSCRAPER</h1>

        </div>

    </header>

    <h1 class=title>ULTRATOP 50</h1>

        <div class="container-one">

            <div class="box-left">

                <h2>NEW THIS WEEK</h2>

                <table id="new">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Artist - Track</th>
                        <th>Copy</th>
                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>

            <div class="box-middle">

                <h2>RISING HITS</h2>

                <table id="top">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Artist - Track</th>
                        <th>Copy</th>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                
            </div>

            <div class="box-right">

                <h2>GONE THIS WEEK</h2>

                <table id="dropped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Artist - Track</th>
                        
                    </tr>


                </table>
                
            </div>



        </div>
   


        
        <div class=container-two>
            <div class=table-left>

                <h2>THIS WEEK</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Artist - Track</th>
                        <th>Movement</th>
                        <th>Copy</th>
                    </tr>

                    <% for (let i = 0; i < top50ArtistsThisWeek.length; i++) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
                            <td id=copyText class=currentTop50ListItem> <%= top50ArtistsThisWeek[i] %> - <%= top50SongsThisWeek[i] %> </td>
                            <td class="ranking"></td>
                            <td><button class="copyButtonCurrent"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                    



                </table>

            </div>

            <div class=table-right>

                <h2>LAST WEEK</h2>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Artist - Track</th>
                        
                    </tr>

                    <% for (let i = 0; i < top50ArtistsLastWeek.length; i++) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
                            <td class=lastTop50ListItem> <%= top50ArtistsLastWeek[i] %> - <%= top50SongsLastWeek[i] %> </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                    



                </table>


            </div>
        </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">

        <div class=footer-disc>
            <p>Disclaimer:</p>
            <p>This webpage was created purely as a project - data for the tables is extracted from https://www.ultratop.be and https://www.shazam.com/gb </p>

        </div>

        <div class=footer-icons>
            <a class=icon href='https://github.com/De-L3ns'><i 
                class="fa fa-github" style="font-size:36px"></i></a><a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/laurens-viaene-90864a1b2/'><i 
                    class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>

        </div>


    </footer>
</body>
<script type ="application/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

My script.Js:

```
// DOM Manipulation for the list items

let currentTop50 = document.getElementsByClassName('currentTop50ListItem');
let lastTop50 = document.getElementsByClassName('lastTop50ListItem');
let growthTable = document.getElementsByClassName('ranking');
let tableNew = document.getElementById("new");
let tableGrowth = document.getElementById("top");
let tableDropped = document.getElementById("dropped");

let dropDown = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");


// special variables
let idNumberNew = 0;
let idNumberGrowth = 0;


for (let i = 0; i < lastTop50.length; i++) {

    lastTop50[i].style.color = "darkred";
    lastTop50[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';


    for (let j = 0; j < currentTop50.length; j++) {

        if (lastTop50[i].innerText == currentTop50[j].innerText) {

            lastTop50[i].style.color = 'black';
            lastTop50[i].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
            

        } 
    }

    if (lastTop50[i].style.color == "darkred") {

        let row = tableDropped.insertRow(-1);
        let cellSpot = row.insertCell(0);
        let cellArtistNumber = row.insertCell(1);
        
        cellSpot.innerHTML = i + 1;
        cellArtistNumber.innerHTML = lastTop50[i].innerHTML;
        


    }

} 

for (let i = 0; i < currentTop50.length; i++) {

    currentTop50[i].style.color = 'green';
    currentTop50[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    currentTop50[i].id = `copyTextCurrent${i}`;

    
    

    for (let j = 0; j < lastTop50.length; j++) {

        if (currentTop50[i].innerText == lastTop50[j].innerText) {

            currentTop50[i].style.color = 'black';
            currentTop50[i].style.fontWeight = 'normal';

            if (i == j) {

                growthTable[i].innerHTML += '0';
                

            } else if (i < j) {
                let growth = j - i;
                growthTable[i].innerHTML += `+${growth}`;
                if (growth > 9) {
                    
                    let row = tableGrowth.insertRow(-1);
                    let cellSpot = row.insertCell(0);
                    let cellArtistNumber = row.insertCell(1);
                    cellArtistNumber.id = `copyTextGrowth${idNumberGrowth}`;
                    idNumberGrowth++;
                    let cellCopy = row.insertCell(2);
                    cellSpot.innerHTML = i + 1;
                    cellArtistNumber.innerHTML = currentTop50[i].innerHTML;
                    cellCopy.innerHTML = '<button class="copyButtonGrowth"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>'

                   

                }

                if (growth > 0) {

                    growthTable[i].style.color = "green";

                } 
                

            } else {

                growthTable[i].innerHTML += `-${i - j}`;
                growthTable[i].style.color = "darkred";
            }
            

        
        }
    }

    if (currentTop50[i].style.color == 'green') {
        
        let row = tableNew.insertRow(-1);
        let cellSpot = row.insertCell(0);
        let cellArtistNumber = row.insertCell(1);
        
        
        let cellCopy = row.insertCell(2);
        cellSpot.innerHTML = i + 1;
        cellArtistNumber.innerHTML = currentTop50[i].innerHTML;
        cellCopy.innerHTML = '<button class="copyButtonNew"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>'
        cellArtistNumber.id = `copyTextNew${idNumberNew}`;
        idNumberNew++;



    }

}

// Button logic for all buttons on the tables

// Current Top 50 buttons

let copyButtonsCurrent = document.getElementsByClassName('copyButtonCurrent');

for (let i = 0; i < copyButtonsCurrent.length; i++) {

    copyButtonsCurrent[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        copyToClipboard((`copyTextCurrent${i}`));

    })

}

// New this week buttons

let copyButtonsNew = document.getElementsByClassName('copyButtonNew');

for (let i = 0; i < copyButtonsNew.length; i++) {

    copyButtonsNew[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        copyToClipboard((`copyTextNew${i}`));

    })

}

// Top Growers buttons

let copyButtonsGrowth = document.getElementsByClassName('copyButtonGrowth');
for (let i = 0; i < copyButtonsGrowth.length; i++) {

    copyButtonsGrowth[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        copyToClipboard((`copyTextGrowth${i}`));

    })
    

}





// re-usable functions

function copyToClipboard(elementID) {

    let element = document.getElementById(elementID);

    let text = element.textContent;
    copyText(text);
    
}

function copyText(text) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    

}
```

My App.Js

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
import fetch from 'node-fetch'; // gets the node-fetch package
import { load } from 'cheerio'; // gets the cheerio package
import moment from 'moment';

// Makes __dirname work
import path from 'path';
import res from 'express/lib/response.js';

const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(decodeURI(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname)));


// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + 'public/img'));

// Views for EJS
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



app.get('', (req, res) => {

    res
        
        
        .render('index', {
            top50ArtistsThisWeek: top50ArtistsThisWeek,
            top50SongsThisWeek: top50SongsThisWeek,
            top50ArtistsLastWeek: top50ArtistsLastWeek,
            top50SongsLastWeek: top50SongsLastWeek,
        })
        
    
    
});

// Listen on port 3000

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`listening on port ${port}`));


// # Functions


const getRawData = (URL) => { // get the data from the website
    return fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            return data;
        });
};


// Website url
const url = 'https://www.ultratop.be/nl/ultratop50'



// extract the previous date from the webpage to generate the URL for last week
const top50Data = await getRawData(url);
const parsedTop50Data = load(top50Data, { decodeEntities: true }, {encoding: null});
let dates = [];

parsedTop50Data('option',".content").each(function (i, e) {
    dates[i] = (parsedTop50Data(this).text());
});

let datePrevWeek = dates[1];
let dateThisWeek = dates[0];

// gather dates from previous week (only work if there are allready dates in the list)
// does not work first week of the year
let day = datePrevWeek.split('/')[0];
let month = datePrevWeek.split('/')[1];
let year = datePrevWeek.split('/')[2];

// get backup dates from current year to perform calculations to get the date prev week 
// backup for first week of the year
let dayBackup = dateThisWeek.split('/')[0];
let monthBackup = dateThisWeek.split('/')[1];
let yearBackup = dateThisWeek.split('/')[2];
let currentWeek = new Date(`${yearBackup}-${monthBackup}-${dayBackup}`);
let lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(currentWeek.getDate() - 7); // decrease 7 days from the current date
let lastWeekFormatted = moment(lastWeek).format('YYYYMMDD'); // format to string with moment method

// Website url from last week
let urlPrevWeek = `${url}/${year}/${year}${month}${day}`

// Alternative year gathering incase of year change
// If one of the dates is undefined (no data) then we use the alternative method to construct the URL

if (day === undefined || month === undefined || year === undefined ) { // === checks for the type of the variable -> undefined = none

    urlPrevWeek = `${url}/${lastWeek.getFullYear()}/${lastWeekFormatted}`;

}


// Script functions

const getTop50Artists = async (url) => {
    const top50Data = await getRawData(url);
    const parsedTop50Data = load(top50Data, { decodeEntities: false });
    let artistList = [];
    

    parsedTop50Data('b',".chart_title").each(function (i, e) {
        artistList[i] = parsedTop50Data(this).text();
        
    });
    
    
    return artistList;
    
};

const getTop50Songs = async (url) => {
    const top50Data = await getRawData(url);
    const parsedTop50Data = load(top50Data, { decodeEntities: false });
    let songList = [];
    
    parsedTop50Data('a', ".chart_title").each(function (i, e) {

        parsedTop50Data(this).contents().map(function(){
            songList[i] = (this.type === 'text') ? parsedTop50Data(this).text()+'' : '';
        }).get().join('');
        
    })

    return songList;
    
}; 

let top50ArtistsThisWeek = await getTop50Artists(url);
let top50SongsThisWeek = await getTop50Songs(url);
let top50ArtistsLastWeek = await getTop50Artists(urlPrevWeek);
let top50SongsLastWeek = await getTop50Songs(urlPrevWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are receiving this error because the script tag in the EJS file is after the body tag. You should place it inside the body or even in the head

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately!